# Is it as fallacy to say that you misunderstand in some unspecifiable way?

Tags: fallacies

Suppose I am presented with an argument, and respond that they have misunderstood something so badly that, while I am clear about what is being said, I cannot say what error the argument (or question) has made, but it has made an error.

Is that a fallacy?

Comment: Perhaps "meta-fallacy" would be a useful description. A direct fallacy would be roughly equivalent to an invalid pattern of reasoning, but here we speak of an unjustified claim about the *soundness* of an argument's premises. Or if we are speaking of validity still, then we might be speaking of something like "the fallacy fallacy," which is the claim that because an argument is fallacious, the conclusion is false.

Comment: This isn't a fallacy (or an argument, for that matter) and not even necessarily wrong. One may be able to detect errors without being able to spell out what they are or to articulate how they know. It is typical with grammar and semantics of words and various other types of ["knowledge how"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/knowledge-how/#Arti).

Comment: well i think you've misunderstood something, but i cannot say what @Conifold

Comment: just a silly joke @Conifold there is a difference between being unsure why and ipse dixit, having no reason why, in that the former is not an argument but a mental state. i don't see why you thought i was asking about the former.

Comment: @Conifold that comment should be an answer, so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

It's the "just because" or "mother knows best" fallacy

> Ipse dixit is an assertion without proof, or a dogmatic expression of
> opinion. The fallacy of defending a proposition by baldly asserting
> that it is "just how it is"

- You have misunderstood
- I have not
- Ipse dixit

Answer (score 0):

Well, an example to drive home the OP's point. Try this on for size:

**The Ontological Argument** (kind courtesy of St. Anselm )

1. If God does not exist then God is not the greatest being imaginable.
2. God is the greatest being imaginable
   Ergo,
3. God exists   (1, 2 Modus Tollens)

The great Bertrand Russell is supposed to have declared the ontological argument as sound. Another luminary, Kurt Gödel, thought it was the best theists had to offer? Why else would he refine it and perfect it?

Something's not quite right, *I know it*, but *I don't know* what exactly!!!

P. S. We should call it **Saint Anselm Syndrome**.

Comment: This is not a bad answer; I could see not upvoting it, but downvoting it, when it brings up such a perspicuous example from the history of philosophy itself, of the OP's curiosity, seems unduly harsh. I suppose that, by proposing his own phrase for the quasi-fallacy(?) in question, that it comes across as "not a peer-reviewed/citation-based answer," but I would like to look into whether there is, in fact, a phrase like "St. Anselm's syndrome" that is current somewhere in the literature...

Comment: @KristianBerry, I'm the undeserving recipient of  your kindness. Gracias, muchas. All I can say is, word has it that one of the toughest theistic arguments to refute is St. Anselm's. There have been attempts, but Kurt Gödel gave it his stamp of approval. Note Gödel's preeminence in the realm of logic. I'll let the argument speak for itself. Remember to survey the philosophical works on the subject. Wikipedia is a good place to start. And yet ... something's off about it ... but what?

Comment: *If God does not exist then God is not the greatest being imaginable.*  Why does something have to exist to be imaginable?

Comment: Russel states explicitly in On Denoting (1905) the opposite of what you say he is supposed (by whom?) to have declared.

Comment: "'The most perfect Being has all perfections; existence is a perfection; therefore the most perfect Being exists' becomes: 'There is one and only one entity x which is most perfect; that one has all perfections; existence is a perfection; therefore that one exists.' As a proof, this fails for want of a proof of the premise."

Comment: @gs, Much obliged. All my info comes from Wikipedia. Did you read the page? I'm more of a *reporter* than an *analyst*. 

Comment: @IdiosyncraticSoul. Anslems's exact words are "that than which nothing greater can be conceived."

Comment: The fact that Gödel made his own version concerns me as an atheist. Gödel was the “spoiler” across many fields, (1) the Gödel Metric proved Einstein wrong in that, General Relativity opens the door to time travel, and (2) the Incompleteness Theorems destroyed Logicism in philosophy of math.

Comment: @AgentSmith you happen to have a reference to a lay explanation of Gödel’s ontological argument? I’d love to dig into it, but I cannot read mathematical logic.

Comment: Basing the existence of God  on what can be conceived seems wrong. If humans were wiped out then their would be no one to conceive of God. So God would cease to exist?

Comment: The argument is just playing with words to sneak the conclusion into the premises. Either greatness implies existence, then God's greatness cannot be a premise (in an argument seeking to prove God's existence), or greatness does not imply existence, then non-existence implying non-greatness cannot be a premise. In short, it's really poor reasoning for an argument so prominent (like most/all apologetics).